# Professional jQuery clone pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be the most common (hopefully in a professional setting) pattern used for copying elements with jQuery only?

I am leaning towards putting the entire div saved in a variable and jQuery clone from it,

ie

```
var temp = $("<div><span>stuff</span></div>");
var newElement = temp.clone();
```

creating the div one by one and using append() and stuff to add elements to each other?
ie

```
var newElement = $("<div></div>");
var span = $("<span>stuff</span>");
span.appendTo(newElement);
```

Or some other way such as cloning straight from an html file?

I think the first one is better because I read that append() functions are expensive compared to just appending strings, and I and design a template in a html file and then copy it over to my .js

Also by copying this way, I will have duplicate ids, which I can differentiate with jquery by finding the one closest to the parent div, however I have read that duplicate IDs is bad. How would I differentiate them?

There are probably multiple ways to do it, and maybe different places would use different patterns, but I think one would generally be agreed upon to be the best.

Also there shouldn't be a loading problem if I keep my template variable in the root of my js file and clone it in functions right?

Comment: Why not [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)?

Comment: I'm using mostly jQuery over standard js, so I thought clone kept it more inline.

Comment: What about https://api.jquery.com/clone/? If you want some html templating, then you should probably get some templating plugin

Comment: Yes, that clone is the one I am using right now. I guess a templating plugin would be idea, but what if one was not available?